# How to attach click event to a Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap tabs. I want to create a tab-based menu with a submenu. On all tabs there is a mouseenter event attached, so when I enter the tab with the mouse pointer there appear links in submenu. But some of the tabs do not need a submenu, so I need attach to them a click event, that recognizes what tab i clicked and redirects me to a page. I attached the click event with this code:

```
 $('#mainTabPanel a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $destination = $(this);

    if ($destination.hash === "#about") {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
});
```

But it's not working. Can you help me?

EDIT

I've made a example in JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Romanus91PL/a12m71pf/5/

When I click the "Bing Link" anchors, they redirect me to the bing.com site. I want to apply such an event too to the About tab (when I click it, it should redirect me to the bing site).

Comment: Can you add your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand Your problem correctly, what about this

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainTabPanel a').mouseover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    $('#mainTabPanel a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.hash === "#about") {
            window.location.replace("https://bing.com");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szepiet83/myqo4wx7/

Answer (score 1):

Please try below given code.It may help you..

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
       console.log(e.target) // activated tab
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it did'nt help. I know what is in the e variable, but I can't launch window.location.replace, it seems that there is something blocking it. Maybe there is something with the bootstrap, that is blocking this action for tabs?